# ARM Template with DSC extension: Powershell file location from local destop

Tags: visual-studio, azure-resource-manager, dsc

I would like to send the ARM template Project with related PS scripts for DSC to a third party. They would probably deploy option in VS to do the deployment. It is possible to attach the DSC script as part of the ARM project and on deploy picks up the dsc script from local disk? Under settings we have "ModulesUrl" it is possible to replace this with another parameter which points to local disk something like c:\myproject\IISInstall.ps1.zip

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('webSrvVmName'))]"
  ],
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "name": "qawebsrv/iisinstall",
  "properties": {
    "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
    "type": "DSC",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "2.19",
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
    "settings": {
      "ModulesUrl": "https://dscscript.blob.core.windows.net/dscscripts/IISInstall.ps1.zip",
      "ConfigurationFunction": "[variables('configurationFunction')]",
      "Properties": {},
      "SasToken": "",
      "wmfVersion": "4.0"
    },
    "protectedSettings": {}
  },
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "VM Extensions"
  },
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're planning to use VS to do the deployment, then VS can stage the DSC package for you - the deployment script in VS does this... it can actually build the DSC package as well, but that has some limitations.

There's nothing magic about the VS script - this repo has a DSC sample that uses the same script used by VS - see: https://github.com/bmoore-msft/AzureRM-Samples/tree/master/VMDSCInstallFile

for a "Hello World" example...

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Closest you can get to this is upload your script to a publicly available place and the VM will pull it.

```
"properties": {
    "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
    "type": "DSC",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "2.20",
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
    "settings": {
        "configuration": {
            "url": "https://github.com/xxx.zip",
            "script": "scriptname.ps1",
            "function": "main"
        },
        "configurationArguments": {}
    },
    "protectedSettings": {}
}
```